# PHP using XPath to find valued tags

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How can I use XPath to get the value of <FL val="Account Owner"> by searching for the <FL val="Account Name"> tag?

I've been using the following PHP / XPath code:

```
$aan = "Company A";
$ContRow = "/results/Accounts/row['FL val=\"Account Name\"'='".$aan."']";
foreach ($Cxml->xpath($ContRow) as $Crow)
  {
    $ao = $Crow->FL[1];
    echo $ao."<br />";
  }
```

and the XML code:

```
<result>
    <Accounts>
        <row no="1">
            <FL val="Account Name">
                <![CDATA[Company A]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Account Owner">
                <![CDATA[Owner's Name]]>
            </FL>
        </row>
    </Accounts>
</result>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression will find every `row` that satisfies having an `<FL val="Account Name">` descendant that contains `"Company A"` and then selects the `<FL val="Account Owner">` element inside:

```
/result/Accounts/row[contains(FL[@val="Account Name"], "Company A")]/FL[@val="Account Owner"]
```

This expression should also do it:

```
/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="Account Name" and contains(.,"Company A")]/following-sibling::FL
```

**Example**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$res = $xpath->query('/result/Accounts/row[contains(FL[@val="Account Name"], "Company A")]/FL[@val="Account Owner"]');

foreach ($res as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the code but still can't get it working. <FL val="Account Owner"> isn't a descendant of <FL val="Account Name">, it's a sibling. But they both sit in the same <row> tag

Comment: @JaceG Could you share what code you have written so far?

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. I have gone through it closely and found that I made a typo when putting it in. But I fixed that and it works perfectly :) Apart from ... I have 269 <row> tags, and the XML file is just over 5000 lines long. I can't get past line 391 because it has an error that says "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/<user>public_html/acct/xpath.php on line 134". Any ideas how to fix this one? It's the last thing to do before my entire project is completed!

Comment: @JaceG Have you established that it's the XPath code itself that's causing it? It could be something else entirely.

Comment: Did a Google search with the error and found a solution - put set_time_limit(0); at the top of my PHP script. All sorted and project complete! Thanks Jack :)